# Unexpected timeout behaviour in Python processes depending on return value of called function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, timeout

Given the following program:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np


def run_process_timeout_wrapper(function, args, timeout):

    def aux(n, out_q):
        res = function(*n)
        out_q.put(res)  # to get result back from thread target

    result_q = multiprocessing.Queue()

    p = Process(target=aux, args=(args, result_q))
    p.start()
    x = result_q.get()
    p.join(timeout=timeout)
    p.terminate()

    if p.is_alive():
        p.terminate()
        raise multiprocessing.TimeoutError("Timed out after waiting for {}s".format(timeout))

    return x


def foo(x):
    return [(np.random.rand(50000), 0.993) for _ in range(10)]


def bar(x):
    return x

def foobar(x):
    res = [(np.random.rand(50000), 0.993) for _ in range(10000)]
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = time.time()
    res = run_process_timeout_wrapper(foo, (110,), 40)
    print(time.time() - t1)

    t1 = time.time()
    res1 = run_process_timeout_wrapper(bar, (110,), 40)
    print(time.time() - t1)

    t1 = time.time()
    res2 = run_process_timeout_wrapper(foobar, (110,), 1)
    print(time.time() - t1)
```

The output of this program is 40seconds for the first process and about 0 for the second. I understand returning the array taking a bit more time than 0 but I am confused as to what is happening. As both foo and bar should probably take less than 40 seconds (the timeout) to compute, I would expect both to finish quickly and returning.

**UPDATE**:

Thank you for the answer regarding the reordering of x.get() with join. However, I found another unexpected behaviour by adding a task that should time out. Running the last part (foobar function) now seems to be non terminating despite the fact that I would expect into to terminate after 1 second and raise a TimeoutError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines):

> #### Joining processes that use queues
>
> Bear in mind that a process that has put items in a queue will wait before terminating until all the buffered items are fed by the
> “feeder” thread to the underlying pipe. (The child process can call
> the Queue.cancel_join_thread method of the queue to avoid this
> behaviour.)
>
> This means that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be
> removed before the process is joined. Otherwise you cannot be sure
> that processes which have put items on the queue will terminate.
> Remember also that non-daemonic processes will be joined
> automatically.

---

So quick workaround will be put `result_q.get()` before `p.join()`:

```
x = result_q.get()
p.join(timeout=timeout)
```

Comment: Thank you. This answered the first of my questions. I added an update that exhibits another odd behaviour after changing the order of get() and join()

Comment: @julian Well, you're creating an extremely large array that needs to be pickled/unpickled 2 times - so that takes lots of time

Comment: No, that's not it. Running print( [(np.random.rand(50000), 0.993) for _ in range(10000)]) in the normal python shell takes less than 5 seconds. Where's I had to stop the program above by hand.